# Regular expression rejecting 0 and 0.0

Tags: regex

Can anyone Please help me to find a regular expression that reject values 0 and 0.0 and accept any other values?

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the best tool for that.

Comment: A regexp seems overkill for this task. Just compare the string as-is. If you really need a regexp, it would be easier to do the inverse and take the values that don't match `/^(0|0\.0)$/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!0(?:\.0)?$).*$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/crVLjO/2)

Comment: It is also rejecting values such as 0.02,0.03. Is there any way to avoid this.

Comment: @Nandu Fixed, I forgot the extra `$` in the negative lookahead